# MySQL Partition based on month-year

Tags: mysql, query, performance, query-performance

Is there a way that I can create a month-year partition on the below table?  Without having to define all the permuations of month/year combos ?

```
CREATE TABLE  visitor_visits (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
  visitor_id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  source varchar(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  medium varchar(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  campaign varchar(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  page varchar(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  landing varchar(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  type enum('fundraiser_view') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  visit_date date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  created_at datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

ALTER TABLE visitor_visits ADD UNIQUE INDEX (visitor_id,type,visit_date);
ALTER TABLE visitor_visits ADD CONSTRAINT FK_visits_visitor_id FOREIGN KEY (visitor_id) REFERENCES visitors(id);
```

Comment: Partitioning does not support foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you must create the PARTITIONs yourself.  I would do it in Perl; do you know that language, or some other?